# Rewrite rules stops working tried flushing on events but didn't worked

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I used to do URL rewriting on WordPress for this I use a code that works perfectly but after sometime it stops working and give 404 error then I do Permalink setting to save once again and it works; every time it stops I do permalink save setting and it works but didn't figure out how to solve this issue permanently.

URL rewrite code:

```
// Rewrite rules
function custom_add_rewrite_rule(){
   
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post') );
    
    if( $posts ){
        
        foreach($posts as $post ){
            
            add_rewrite_rule( 
                $post->post_name . '/download/?$', 
                'index.php?name=' . $post->post_name . '&post_action=download&post_id=' . $post->ID, 
                'top' 
            );   
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is in `function.php`. To solve this I tried by flushing rules on every post save/update using the below code:

```
// flush rewrite rule on post/update
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function' );
function my_save_post_function( $post_id ) {
  $maybe_some_extra_logic = true; // if applicable
  if ( $maybe_some_extra_logic && ! has_action( 'shutdown', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules' ) ) {
    add_action( 'shutdown', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules', 9999 ); // set suitable priority
  }
}

function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Although it isn't wrong, binding permalinks to individual posts, and rebuilding the whole permalink system on save seems overkill and problematic. Could you instead have a single top-rule of something like `([^/]+)/download/?$` that is only ever needed to be added once?

Comment: No i don't have such rule the above code works on post update but if i do not do post upadating for long then again it give 404. How do i solve this?